# Using Farkas Lemma to deduce $0^Tx<-1$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

Given the polyhedron $P=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\ : Ax\leq b\}$ for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and a vector $w \in \mathbb{Z}^n$. Now consider $\hat{P} = \{x \in P : w^Tx \leq \lfloor x \rfloor \}$. If we know that $\hat{P} = \emptyset$, then why can we deduce with Farkas' Lemma that $0^Tx\leq -1$?

Comment: But $0^Tx=0$ for any $x$?

Comment: What is $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ supposed to mean? From the context in which you use it, it should be a scalar, but the only definition I can imagine would make it a vector. Also, the title states a strict inequality, while the question body states a weak one.